# Spsite.usage.storage gives access denied exception

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, access-denied, storage

I am getting an access denied exception while executing `SPSite.Usage.Storage` with Contribute access, even though I have used run with elevated privileges. It works okay when I run it with site owner permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Contribute level permission is not sufficient to get the details you are looking for. Contribute permission basically entails (as per MSDN) - "Enables users to manage personal views, edit items and user information, delete versions in existing lists and document libraries, and add, remove, and update personal Web Parts"

You need to have a minimum of "Manage" permissions. Better upgrade your permission levels to either of these and then try again -

- Full Control
- Design

More about permissions can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx#section2)

Comment: But I am also using run with elewated privilage, and in this case code should run with app pool account and app pool has full control, still it is giving thea same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign Auditor permission to the user (including application pool account).

Central administration -> Manage web applications -> Select the web application -> User policy

Comment: App pool account already has Full control